# Fastest algorithm to win a combination game

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I was playing a game called [Alchemy Merge](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ilyin.alchemy&hl=en_IN&gl=US), where you have to combine different elements to create a new one. It starts with 4 basic elements *i.e., Air, Fire, Soil and Water* and combining this we get new elements. Now, I have completed the game and simultaneously noted each entry as following

```
Air
Fire
Soil
Water
Heat = Air + Fire
Plant = Soil + Water
Tree = Plant + Plant
Forest = Tree + Tree
```

... and the list continues for roughly 400 elements. Now, I have two questions regarding this.

1. What is the fastest algorithm to complete the game with minimum steps?
2. What is the best approach to determine the **depth** of an element in minimum time? By the term "depth", I am referring to the number of combinations required to get the element...

```
depth(Water) = 0 #primary element
depth(Plant) = 1 #(soil + water) 
#calculation for depth is stopped as it reaches the primary elements
```

As @trincot points out, here are a few more examples to clarify the "depth"

```
Algae = Plant + Water.
```

Now, to get Algae, we need 2 combinations,

```
1. Plant = Soil + Water
2. Algae = Plant + Water
```

So the depth(Algae) will be 2.

Taking another example, consider the following combinations...

```
Stone = Soil + Soil
Sand = Stone + Water
Glass = Sand + Fire
Time = Glass + Sand
```

Now, calculating depth(Time), but in reverse order...

```
1. Time = Sand + Glass
2.          = (Stone+Water) + Glass
3.          = ((Soil + Soil) + Water) + Glass
4.          = ((Soil + Soil) + Water) + (Sand + Fire)
5.          = ((Soil + Soil) + Water) + ((Stone+Water) + Fire)
6.          = ((Soil + Soil) + Water) + (((Soil + Soil)+Water) + Fire)
```

So, depth(Time) = 6

Thank you.

Comment: The definition of *depth* is ambiguous. Can you extend the example with more combinations that do not have two of the same elements (so not like "tree + tree" or "plant + plant")? Maybe some need 3 elements? And then give the depth? Are there sometimes *alternative* ways to create an element? If so, can your example also be such that it shows this possibility?

Comment: @trincot I have updated the question with a more elaborated example. I hope it will clarify the definition of *depth*.

Comment: Thanks. I see some discrepancy. If I apply the breakdown system of `Time` on your earlier example of `Tree`, I get a "depth" of 3 for `Tree`. `1. Tree = Plant + Plant, 2. = (Soil + Water) + Plant, 3. (Soil + Water) + (Soil + Water)`. ....Can you harmonise?

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing it out. It should be 3. I mistook my calculation for the same elements.

Comment: You ask about *minimum* steps, but the number of steps looks fixed for each element (i.e., "minimum" doesn't seem to make sense).

Comment: What does "complete the game" mean?

Comment: *Complete the game* means discovering each element.

Comment: If you know all possible combinations beforehand, then it requires a constant step. But, assuming, that's not the case, I am trying to figure out a strategy so that, it requires minimum steps to get max number of elements.

Comment: Can it be seen as some form of term rewriting and looking for a fixpoint?

Comment: What would be the depth of `Foo = Air + Fire + Soil`? 1 or 2?

Comment: It will be 1, since all the elements are primary.

Comment: @KellyBundy According to the game, you can add at max 3 elements at a time. Depth of  Foo will be 2 if you need a composite element in between: `Bar = Air + Fire,
Foo = Bar + Soil`

Comment: Ok, I just originally thought it's the number of additions (i.e., number of `+`).

Comment: If element X takes 6 steps, and element Y=X+Air so that Y takes 7 steps, what is the total? 13 or 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a graph problem, more specifically the graph is a directed, acyclic graph (DAG),
where each node is an element, and outgoing edges go to the element(s) that are needed
to build that element. If the same element is needed multiple times, that just means there
are two edges connecting the two nodes. The "initial" four elements are represented by leaf-nodes,
as they don't have outgoing edges.

Once you have this DAG available in a practical data structure, the problem of creating a target element
comes down to traversing the dependent nodes in bottom-up fashion.

The notion of "depth" you present is actually not the term that would be used in the graph problem. You want to actually count the number of visited internal nodes in a traversal that can be executed from the target node to reach the leaves (note some nodes can be visited multiple times, and leaves don't count).

To implement an algorithm, first choose a graph data structure that is convenient to quickly find a node, so a hash table (hash map, dictionary) would be a good choice.
For each entry you could then have an array of references to child nodes, that reference the components that are needed.

We can represent such a structure in JSON format:

```json
{
    "Air": [],
    "Fire": [],
    "Soil": [],
    "Water": [],
    "Heat": ["Air", "Fire"],
    "Plant": ["Soil", "Water"],
    "Tree": ["Plant", "Plant"],
    "Forest": ["Tree", "Tree"],
    "Algae": ["Plant", "Water"],
    "Stone": ["Soil", "Soil"],
    "Sand": ["Stone", "Water"],
    "Glass": ["Sand", "Fire"],
    "Time": ["Glass", "Sand"]  
}
```

The traversal of all paths that lead to the leaves can be done with a depth-first traversal, more specifically, with a post-order traversal.
That way the traversal will list the edges (i.e. the actions to take) in a chronological (topological) order.

Here is an implementation in JavaScript, with a run for the "Time" element:

```js
const graph = {
    "Air": [],
    "Fire": [],
    "Soil": [],
    "Water": [],
    "Heat": ["Air", "Fire"],
    "Plant": ["Soil", "Water"],
    "Tree": ["Plant", "Plant"],
    "Forest": ["Tree", "Tree"],
    "Algae": ["Plant", "Water"],
    "Stone": ["Soil", "Soil"],
    "Sand": ["Stone", "Water"],
    "Glass": ["Sand", "Fire"],
    "Time": ["Glass", "Sand"]  
};

function build(target) {
    if (graph[target].length == 0) { // It is a leaf
        return []; // No action needed
    }
    let actions = [];
    for (let child of graph[target]) {
        actions.push(...build(child));
    }
    actions.push("Use " + graph[target] + " to create " + target);
    return actions;
}

let actions = build("Time");
console.log(actions);
```

The size of the returned array of *steps* is what you called "depth" (6 in the example of "Time").

If you're only interested in the size and not the steps themselves, it is easy to simplify the above code to just return a step counter.

It would also be appropriate to use memoization, i.e. store calculated "depths" with each node so you would not do the calculation a second time.

Here is a version that only returns the step-count and uses memoization:

```js
const graph = {
    "Air": [],
    "Fire": [],
    "Soil": [],
    "Water": [],
    "Heat": ["Air", "Fire"],
    "Plant": ["Soil", "Water"],
    "Tree": ["Plant", "Plant"],
    "Forest": ["Tree", "Tree"],
    "Algae": ["Plant", "Water"],
    "Stone": ["Soil", "Soil"],
    "Sand": ["Stone", "Water"],
    "Glass": ["Sand", "Fire"],
    "Time": ["Glass", "Sand"]  
};

const steps = {}; // Memoization of the number of steps needed for a component 

function build(target) {
    if (graph[target].length == 0) { // It is a leaf
        return 0; // No action needed
    }
    if (target in steps) { // We have calculated this before
        return steps[target];
    }
    let actionCount = 1;
    for (let child of graph[target]) {
        actionCount += build(child);
    }
    // Store for later reuse
    steps[target] = actionCount;
    return actionCount;
}

let actionCount = build("Time");
console.log(actionCount);
```

For "discovering" (i.e. building) all nodes, and to minimise the number of steps for it, we should find the "roots" of the graph, the nodes that have no parent (i.e. elements which are not used as component for another). When we have built those, we know we will have built all.

As we need to know the children, the build count, the parents for each node, it is time to create a Node class, and have these as instance properties.

Here it is an implementation and run on the larger JSON you provided:

```js
class Node {
    constructor(element) {
        this.element = element;
        this.children = [];
        this.parents = [];
        this.buildCount = 0; // Default
    }
    build() {
        if (this.children.length > 0 && this.buildCount == 0) { // Not yet calculated
            this.buildCount = 1; // Count the last step of combining the children
            for (let child of this.children) {
                this.buildCount += child.build();
            }
        }
        return this.buildCount;
    }
}

function solve(adjacency) {
    const graph = {};
    // Create a node instance for each element
    for (const element in adjacency) {
        graph[element] = new Node(element);
    }
    // Populate children & parents lists of each node
    for (const element in adjacency) {
        for (const child of adjacency[element]) {
            graph[element].children.push(graph[child]);
            graph[child].parents.push(graph[element]);
        }
    }
    let buildCount = 0;
    // Explicitly build all nodes that have no parent (are not used for another element)
    for (const node of Object.values(graph)) {
        if (node.parents.length == 0) {
            buildCount += node.build();
        }
    }
    return buildCount;
}

// Run on the larger JSON:
const adjacency = {"Air": [],"Fire": [],"Soil": [],"Water": [],"Acorn" : ["Time" , "Tree"],"Adhesive tape" : ["Glue" , "Ribbon"],"Aircraft" : ["Air" , "Metal"],"Airship" : ["Balloon" , "Metal" , "Rope"],"Algae" : ["Plant" , "Water"],"Anchor" : ["Chain" , "Metal" , "Water"],"Angel" : ["Bird" , "Human"],"Anvil" : ["Hammer" , "Human"],"Apple" : ["Gravity" , "Tree"],"Aquarium" : ["Fish" , "Glass" , "Water"],"Armor" : ["Clothes" , "Metal"],"Arrow" : ["Blade" , "Feather" , "Stick"],"Ash" : ["Bonfire" , "Water"],"Asteroid" : ["Space" , "Stone"],"Atom" : ["Electron" , "Neutron" , "Proton"],"Axe" : ["Blade" , "Stick" , "Wood"],"Baby" : ["Human" , "Human" , "Love"],"Bacteria" : ["Life" , "Ocean"],"Ball" : ["Air" , "Rubber"],"Balloon" : ["Air" , "Rope" , "Rubber"],"Bandage" : ["Cloth" , "Ribbon"],"Bank" : ["House" , "Money"],"Baobab" : ["Savannah" , "Tree"],"Barrel" : ["Board" , "Circle" , "Metal"],"Bat" : ["Air" , "Blood"],"Battery" : ["Electricity" , "Energy" , "Metal"],"Beach" : ["Ocean" , "Sand"],"Bear" : ["Cave" , "Claw"],"Bed" : ["Pillow" , "Wood"],"Bee" : ["Flower" , "Insect"],"Beer" : ["Water" , "Wheat"],"Binoculars" : ["Telescope" , "Telescope"],"Bird" : ["Air" , "Life"],"Birdhouse" : ["Bird" , "House"],"Bitcoin" : ["Coin" , "Electricity"],"Black hole" : ["Gravity" , "Gravity" , "Gravity"],"Blade" : ["Metal" , "Tool"],"Blood" : ["Blade" , "Human"],"Boar" : ["Forest" , "Pig"],"Board" : ["Tool" , "Wood" , "Wood"],"Boat" : ["Paddle" , "Raft"],"Bone" : ["Sword" , "Zombie"],"Bonfire" : ["Fire" , "Stick" , "Stick"],"Book" : ["Cardboard" , "Ink" , "Paper"],"Bottle" : ["Plastic" , "Water"],"Bow" : ["Rope" , "Stick"],"Box" : ["Cardboard" , "Cardboard"],"Brain" : ["Neuron" , "Neuron" , "Neuron"],"Bread" : ["Dough" , "Fire"],"Brick" : ["Clay" , "Fire"],"Brush" : ["Paper" , "Tool"],"Bubble" : ["Air" , "Soap"],"Bucket" : ["Metal" , "Plastic" , "Water"],"Bug" : ["Insect" , "Tree"],"Bulb" : ["Electricity" , "Glass"],"Butterfly" : ["Caterpillar" , "Time"],"Cacao" : ["Sun" , "Tree"],"Cactus" : ["Needle" , "Plant"],"Cake" : ["Dough" , "Ice cream"],"Calendar" : ["Paper" , "Time"],"Camel" : ["Desert" , "Horse"],"Camouflage" : ["Chameleon" , "Cloth"],"Candle" : ["Fire" , "Wax"],"Candy" : ["Chocolate" , "Paper"],"Canon" : ["Gunpowder" , "Pipe"],"Car" : ["Road" , "Wheel"],"Cardboard" : ["Paper" , "Paper"],"Castle" : ["Tower" , "Wall"],"Cat" : ["Human" , "Tiger"],"Caterpillar" : ["Earthworm" , "Plant"],"Cave" : ["Mountain" , "Time"],"Centaur" : ["Horse" , "Human"],"Ceramic" : ["Clay" , "Heat"],"Cerberus" : ["Dog" , "Dog" , "Dog"],"Chain" : ["Metal" , "Rope"],"Chalk" : ["Limestone" , "Pencil"],"Chameleon" : ["Lizard" , "Rainbow"],"Cheese" : ["Milk" , "Time"],"Cheetah" : ["Cat" , "Savannah" , "Wind"],"Chest" : ["Box" , "Wood"],"Chocolate" : ["Cacao" , "Sugar"],"Christmas tree" : ["Garland" , "Spruce" , "Star"],"Circle" : ["Dividers" , "Paper"],"Circus" : ["Clown" , "House"],"Claw" : ["Blade" , "Bone"],"Clay" : ["River" , "Shovel"],"Clock" : ["Battery" , "Time"],"Cloth" : ["Thread" , "Thread"],"Clothes" : ["Cloth" , "Needle"],"Cloud" : ["Air" , "Water"],"Clown" : ["Holiday" , "Human"],"Coal" : ["Fire" , "Plant"],"Cobweb" : ["Fly" , "Spider"],"Coffee" : ["Cacao" , "Heat" , "Water"],"Coin" : ["Circle" , "Gold"],"Comb" : ["Hair" , "Plastic"],"Compass" : ["Electricity" , "Magnet"],"Concrete" : ["Sand" , "Water"],"Cookie" : ["Cacao" , "Dough" , "Milk"],"Cotton" : ["Cloud" , "Grass"],"Cow" : ["Life" , "Meadow"],"Crab" : ["Fish" , "Scissors"],"Crocodile" : ["Lizard" , "Swamp"],"Crossbow" : ["Bow" , "Metal"],"Crown" : ["Gem" , "Gold"],"Death" : ["Life" , "Time"],"Deer" : ["Forest" , "Horse"],"Desert" : ["Sand" , "Sun"],"Diamond" : ["Coal" , "Pressure"],"Dinosaur" : ["Fossil" , "Life"],"Dirt" : ["Ash" , "Water"],"Dividers" : ["Needle" , "Pencil"],"Doctor" : ["Human" , "Medicine"],"Dog" : ["Human" , "Wolf"],"Door" : ["Board" , "Wall"],"Dough" : ["Flour" , "Water"],"Dragon" : ["Fire" , "Lizard"],"Drum" : ["Barrel" , "Leather"],"Duck" : ["Bird" , "Lake"],"Dynamite" : ["Gunpowder" , "Rope"],"Eagle" : ["Bird" , "Mountain"],"Earthworm" : ["Life" , "Soil"],"Eclipse" : ["Moon" , "Sun"],"Eel" : ["Earthworm" , "Electricity"],"Egg" : ["Bird" , "Bird"],"Electricity" : ["Metal" , "Thunderbolt"],"Electron" : ["Electricity" , "Electricity"],"Energy" : ["Thunderbolt" , "Thunderbolt"],"Engine" : ["Metal" , "Steam"],"Explosion" : ["Fire" , "Gunpowder"],"Eye" : ["Lens" , "Life"],"Fangs" : ["Blade" , "Tooth"],"Fat" : ["Blade" , "Pig"],"Feather" : ["Bird" , "Hammer"],"Firefly" : ["Bulb" , "Insect"],"Fireworks" : ["Explosion" , "Rocket"],"Fish" : ["Life" , "Water"],"Fishing rod" : ["Earthworm" , "Rope" , "Stick"],"Flag" : ["Cloth" , "Stick"],"Flashlight" : ["Battery" , "Light"],"Flask" : ["Glass" , "Water"],"Flour" : ["Wheat" , "Windmill"],"Flower" : ["Life" , "Plant"],"Flute" : ["Pipe" , "Wind"],"Fly" : ["Air" , "Insect"],"Footwear" : ["Cloth" , "Soil"],"Forest" : ["Tree" , "Tree"],"Fork" : ["Pitchfork" , "Steak"],"Fossil" : ["Brush" , "Shovel" , "Soil"],"Fountain" : ["Pressure" , "Water"],"Fridge" : ["Electricity" , "Frost"],"Fried egg" : ["Egg" , "Fire"],"Frog" : ["Life" , "Swamp"],"Frost" : ["Air" , "Wind"],"Furnace" : ["Coal" , "Fire" , "Stone"],"Garland" : ["Bulb" , "Bulb" , "Bulb"],"Gasoline" : ["Petroleum" , "Steam"],"Gear" : ["Metal" , "Wheel"],"Gem" : ["Mountain" , "Pickaxe"],"Ghost" : ["Death" , "Human"],"Gift" : ["Box" , "Ribbon"],"Glass" : ["Fire" , "Sand"],"Glasses" : ["Eye" , "Lens" , "Plastic"],"Glue" : ["Flour" , "Heat" , "Water"],"Gold" : ["Gem" , "Metal"],"Golem" : ["Life" , "Stone"],"Grapes" : ["Plant" , "Stick" , "Sun"],"Grass" : ["Plant" , "Soil"],"Grasshopper" : ["Grass" , "Insect"],"Gravity" : ["Soil" , "Soil" , "Soil"],"Greenhouse" : ["Glass" , "Plant"],"Guitar" : ["String" , "String" , "Wood"],"Gunpowder" : ["Coal" , "Saltpeter"],"Hair" : ["Human" , "Wax"],"Hammer" : ["Stick" , "Stone"],"Hammerhead shark" : ["Fish" , "Hammer"],"Hamster" : ["Mouse" , "Wheat"],"Hand fan" : ["Paper" , "Wind"],"Harp" : ["Bow" , "String"],"Hay" : ["Grass" , "Heat"],"Healing potion" : ["Flask" , "Life"],"Health" : ["Apple" , "Human"],"Heart" : ["Blood" , "Engine"],"Heat" : ["Air" , "Fire"],"Hedgehog" : ["Mouse" , "Needle"],"Hen" : ["Bird" , "Wheat"],"Hippo" : ["Cow" , "River"],"Holiday" : ["Balloon" , "Cake" , "Fireworks"],"Honey" : ["Bee" , "Flower"],"Hookah" : ["Flask" , "Steam" , "Tobacco"],"Horns" : ["Blade" , "Bone" , "Bone"],"Horse" : ["Hay" , "Life"],"Hospital" : ["Health" , "House"],"House" : ["Concrete" , "Glass" , "Wood"],"Human" : ["Cave" , "Life"],"Hydrogen" : ["Sun" , "Time"],"Hyena" : ["Dog" , "Savannah"],"Ice" : ["Frost" , "Water"],"Ice cream" : ["Ice" , "Sugar"],"Iceberg" : ["Ice" , "Water"],"Ink" : ["Octopus" , "Pressure"],"Insect" : ["Earthworm" , "Soil"],"Island" : ["Ocean" , "Soil"],"Jungle" : ["Forest" , "Rain"],"Kettlebell" : ["Gravity" , "Metal"],"Key" : ["Lock" , "Tool"],"King" : ["Crown" , "Human"],"Kite" : ["Air" , "Cloth" , "Rope"],"Knight" : ["Armor" , "Human" , "Sword"],"Lake" : ["Water" , "Water"],"Lava" : ["Fire" , "Soil"],"Leaf" : ["Tree" , "Wind"],"Leather" : ["Hammer" , "Pig"],"Leech" : ["Blood" , "Earthworm"],"Lens" : ["Glass" , "Light"],"Lever" : ["Gear" , "Stick"],"Life" : ["Energy" , "Water"],"Light" : ["Sky" , "Sun"],"Lighthouse" : ["Light" , "Tower"],"Limestone" : ["River" , "Stone"],"Lion" : ["Cat" , "Savannah"],"Lizard" : ["Grass" , "Life"],"Lock" : ["Chest" , "Gear"],"Locomotive" : ["Car" , "Railway"],"Lollipop" : ["Candy" , "Stick"],"Love" : ["Human" , "Human"],"Magic wand" : ["Star" , "Stick"],"Magnet" : ["Electricity" , "Metal"],"Mana potion" : ["Flask" , "Star"],"Mantis" : ["Insect" , "Leaf"],"Map" : ["Compass" , "Paper"],"Mask" : ["Cloth" , "Rope"],"Match" : ["Coal" , "Stick"],"Meadow" : ["Grass" , "Soil"],"Meat" : ["Blade" , "Cow"],"Medicine" : ["Bacteria" , "Health"],"Mercury" : ["Silver" , "Water"],"Mermaid" : ["Fish" , "Human"],"Metal" : ["Fire" , "Stone"],"Meteor" : ["Asteroid" , "Fire"],"Microphone" : ["Sound" , "Stick"],"Milk" : ["Bucket" , "Cow"],"Mine" : ["Cave" , "Pickaxe"],"Minotaur" : ["Cow" , "Human"],"Mirror" : ["Glass" , "Light" , "Water"],"Moat" : ["Castle" , "River"],"Mole" : ["Mouse" , "Soil"],"Molecule" : ["Atom" , "Atom"],"Money" : ["Gold" , "Paper"],"Monkey" : ["Life" , "Tree"],"Moon" : ["Sky" , "Stone"],"Mosquito" : ["Blood" , "Fly"],"Mountain" : ["Soil" , "Stone"],"Mouse" : ["Life" , "Wheat"],"Mummy" : ["Bandage" , "Human"],"Mushroom" : ["Grass" , "Rain"],"Music" : ["Needle" , "Vinyl disk"],"Nail" : ["Hammer" , "Metal" , "Stick"],"Needle" : ["Metal" , "Thread"],"Nest" : ["Bird" , "Egg" , "Tree"],"Net" : ["Cobweb" , "Water"],"Neuron" : ["Electricity" , "Life"],"Neutron" : ["Electron" , "Proton"],"Nunchaku" : ["Chain" , "Stick" , "Stick"],"Obsidian" : ["Lava" , "Water"],"Ocean" : ["Water" , "Water" , "Water"],"Octopus" : ["Fish" , "Vacuum"],"Orca" : ["Ice" , "Whale"],"Ore" : ["Mine" , "Pickaxe"],"Ostrich" : ["Bird" , "Sand"],"Owl" : ["Bird" , "Claw"],"Oxygen" : ["Plant" , "Sun"],"Ozone" : ["Oxygen" , "Sun"],"Paddle" : ["Stick" , "Water"],"Paints" : ["Board" , "Rainbow"],"Panda" : ["Bear" , "Jungle"],"Paper" : ["Tool" , "Wood"],"Parrot" : ["Bird" , "Jungle"],"Pearl" : ["Gem" , "Water"],"Pegasus" : ["Bird" , "Horse"],"Pen" : ["Ink" , "Plastic"],"Pencil" : ["Coal" , "Wood"],"Penguin" : ["Bird" , "Frost"],"Petroleum" : ["Fossil" , "Plant" , "Soil"],"Phoenix" : ["Bird" , "Fire"],"Photo camera" : ["Light" , "Metal" , "Paper"],"Pickaxe" : ["Mountain" , "Tool"],"Picture" : ["Brush" , "Paints" , "Paper"],"Pie" : ["Apple" , "Flour"],"Pig" : ["Dirt" , "Life"],"Pigeon" : ["Bird" , "Bread"],"Pillow" : ["Cloth" , "Feather"],"Pipe" : ["Air" , "Metal" , "Stick"],"Pitchfork" : ["Hay" , "Tool"],"Plant" : ["Soil" , "Water"],"Plastic" : ["Coal" , "Petroleum"],"Plunger" : ["Rubber" , "Stick" , "Vacuum"],"Poison" : ["Flask" , "Snake"],"Polar bear" : ["Bear" , "Snow"],"Potion of Speed" : ["Flask" , "Wind"],"Potion of Strength" : ["Flask" , "Mountain"],"Potion of Wisdom" : ["Flask" , "Owl"],"Pressure" : ["Air" , "Heat"],"Propane" : ["Fire" , "Petroleum"],"Proton" : ["Electron" , "Gravity"],"Puddle" : ["Road" , "Water"],"Pyramid" : ["Mountain" , "Sand"],"Radio" : ["Metal" , "Sound"],"Raft" : ["Water" , "Wood"],"Railway" : ["Metal" , "Road"],"Rain" : ["Cloud" , "Water"],"Rainbow" : ["Rain" , "Sun"],"Raincoat" : ["Clothes" , "Rain"],"Rake" : ["Comb" , "Stick"],"Rhinoceros" : ["Horns" , "Savannah"],"Ribbon" : ["Cloth" , "Scissors"],"Ring" : ["Circle" , "Metal"],"River" : ["Soil" , "Water" , "Water"],"Road" : ["Concrete" , "Soil"],"Robot" : ["Battery" , "Human"],"Rocket" : ["Fire" , "Pipe"],"Rope" : ["Thread" , "Thread" , "Thread"],"Rose" : ["Flower" , "Love"],"Rubber" : ["Petroleum" , "Water"],"Ruler" : ["Board" , "Pencil"],"Safe" : ["Lock" , "Money"],"Salt" : ["Heat" , "Ocean"],"Saltpeter" : ["Limestone" , "Plant"],"Sand" : ["Stone" , "Water"],"Savannah" : ["Grass" , "Soil" , "Sun"],"Scalpel" : ["Blade" , "Health"],"Scissors" : ["Blade" , "Blade"],"Scoop-net" : ["Net" , "Stick"],"Scooter" : ["Wheel" , "Wheel"],"Scorpion" : ["Crab" , "Desert"],"Sculpture" : ["Human" , "Stone"],"Sea cow" : ["Cow" , "Water"],"Seagull" : ["Bird" , "Ocean"],"Seahorse" : ["Fish" , "Horse"],"Sewing machine" : ["Electricity" , "Needle"],"Shark" : ["Fish" , "Tooth"],"Sheep" : ["Cloud" , "Life"],"Shield" : ["Board" , "Metal"],"Ship" : ["Cloth" , "Water" , "Wood"],"Shovel" : ["Soil" , "Tool"],"Silver" : ["Coin" , "Furnace"],"Skateboard" : ["Board" , "Wheel"],"Skates" : ["Blade" , "Footwear" , "Ice"],"Skull" : ["Bone" , "Brain"],"Sky" : ["Air" , "Air" , "Air"],"Slingshot" : ["Rubber" , "Stick"],"Smartphone" : ["Microphone" , "Radio"],"Snail" : ["Caterpillar" , "Glue"],"Snake" : ["Earthworm" , "Fangs"],"Snow" : ["Frost" , "Rain"],"Snowman" : ["Human" , "Snow"],"Soap" : ["Ash" , "Fat"],"Soda" : ["Air" , "Sugar" , "Water"],"Solar panel" : ["Energy" , "Sun"],"Sound" : ["Air" , "Explosion"],"Space" : ["Sky" , "Star"],"Spear" : ["Blade" , "Stick" , "Stick"],"Sphinx" : ["Human" , "Lion"],"Spider" : ["Insect" , "Insect"],"Spine" : ["Bone" , "Neuron"],"Sport" : ["Human" , "Kettlebell"],"Spruce" : ["Needle" , "Tree"],"Spyglass" : ["Lens" , "Pipe"],"Squirrel" : ["Acorn" , "Mouse"],"Star" : ["Sky" , "Telescope"],"Starfish" : ["Ocean" , "Star"],"Steak" : ["Fire" , "Meat"],"Steam" : ["Fire" , "Water"],"Stick" : ["Blade" , "Plant"],"Stone" : ["Soil" , "Soil"],"Stopwatch" : ["Ruler" , "Time"],"String" : ["Sound" , "Thread"],"Stump" : ["Axe" , "Tree"],"Sugar" : ["Sugar cane" , "Windmill"],"Sugar cane" : ["Plant" , "Stick" , "Water"],"Sulfur" : ["Ash" , "Lava"],"Sulfuric acid" : ["Hydrogen" , "Oxygen" , "Sulfur"],"Sun" : ["Fire" , "Sky"],"Sunflower" : ["Flower" , "Sun"],"Surfboard" : ["Board" , "Wave"],"Sushi" : ["Algae" , "Fish"],"Swamp" : ["Grass" , "Lake"],"Sword" : ["Blade" , "Stick"],"Swordfish" : ["Fish" , "Sword"],"Syringe" : ["Health" , "Needle"],"Tank" : ["Metal" , "Turtle"],"Tape measure" : ["Ribbon" , "Ruler"],"Tea" : ["Heat" , "Plant" , "Water"],"Tear" : ["Eye" , "Water"],"Telescope" : ["Lens" , "Sky"],"Tent" : ["Cloth" , "House" , "Stick"],"Thermometer" : ["Heat" , "Mercury"],"Thread" : ["Cobweb" , "Cobweb"],"Thunderbolt" : ["Cloud" , "Cloud" , "Cloud"],"Tide" : ["Moon" , "Ocean"],"Tiger" : ["Jungle" , "Life"],"Time" : ["Glass" , "Sand"],"Tobacco" : ["Plant" , "Steam"],"Tool" : ["Human" , "Metal" , "Wood"],"Tooth" : ["Bone" , "Pressure"],"Toothbrush" : ["Tool" , "Tooth"],"Toothpaste" : ["Health" , "Tooth"],"Toothpick" : ["Stick" , "Tooth"],"Torch" : ["Fire" , "Stick"],"Tornado" : ["Energy" , "Wind"],"Tower" : ["House" , "House"],"Traffic light" : ["Garland" , "Road"],"Treasure" : ["Chest" , "Island"],"Tree" : ["Plant" , "Plant"],"Trojan horse" : ["Horse" , "Wood"],"Turtle" : ["Egg" , "Sand"],"Umbrella" : ["Cloth" , "Rain"],"Unicorn" : ["Horse" , "Magic wand"],"Vacuum" : ["Glass" , "Space"],"Vampire" : ["Blood" , "Human"],"Vinyl disk" : ["Plastic" , "Wax"],"Violin" : ["String" , "Wood"],"Volcano" : ["Lava" , "Mountain"],"Wall" : ["Brick" , "Concrete"],"Wallpaper" : ["Glue" , "Paper" , "Wall"],"Walrus" : ["Fangs" , "Sea cow"],"Waterfall" : ["Mountain" , "Water"],"Wave" : ["Energy" , "Ocean"],"Wax" : ["Bee" , "Bee"],"Well" : ["Bucket" , "Shovel" , "Soil"],"Werewolf" : ["Human" , "Moon" , "Wolf"],"Whale" : ["Fish" , "Fountain"],"Wheat" : ["Shovel" , "Soil" , "Water"],"Wheel" : ["Air" , "Pressure" , "Rubber"],"Wig" : ["Hair" , "Hair"],"Wind" : ["Air" , "Air"],"Windmill" : ["Stone" , "Wind"],"Window" : ["Glass" , "Wood"],"Wine" : ["Grapes" , "Water"],"Wire" : ["Electricity" , "Metal" , "Plastic"],"Wolf" : ["Forest" , "Life"],"Wood" : ["Forest" , "Human"],"Woodpecker" : ["Bird" , "Wood"],"Wool" : ["Scissors" , "Sheep"],"Zebra" : ["Horse" , "Savannah"],"Zombie" :["Death", "Life"]};
const buildCount = solve(adjacency);
console.log("Total number of steps to discover all elements:", buildCount);
```

The output is 27435.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I have just got one question in my mind. Is it possible to count the total number of steps, to complete the game? I have uploaded the json [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/yoursamlan/430dc84f21bae3e3702862f60a7ad417/raw/db8ba0f06006ff12b94a22b25614a104620566a8/alchemy.json)

Comment: Sure, I can do that, but your JSON has no definition of "Zombie"...

Comment: Sorry, I missed that in haste. I have updated the JSON.

Comment: @KellyBundy Check [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/yoursamlan/430dc84f21bae3e3702862f60a7ad417/raw/5bebfaf2fc7edd623034437f55615adbf650af9c/alchemy.json)

Comment: @Kelly, You're right that the order influences the result. I have revised the last part of my answer, with an algorithm that focuses on creating the "roots" of the graph. I believe this minimises the sum of this "build count". So the count is back to 27435.

Comment: Ok, I updated my Python program to that interpretation and get 27435 as well.

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answer pointed out, this is a directed acyclic graph problem.
The nodes are composed elements, the leafs are basic elements.
In order to calculate the depth, you just traverse the tree to find out.

In Haskell, this looks rather neat (while at first thought I considered Prolog for that, I settled with Haskell as it is really pretty in this case).

```hs
-- The base elements are simply numbers
-- (could be strings as well - but that would just be eye candy).

data Element =
    Basic(Integer)
  | Composed(Element,Element)
  deriving (Show,Eq)

depth:: Element -> Integer
depth (Basic _) = 0
depth (Composed(a, b)) =
  1 + max (depth a) (depth b)

air = Basic 1
fire = Basic 2
soil = Basic 3
water = Basic 4

heat = Composed(air,fire)
plant = Composed(soil,water)
algae = Composed(plant,water)
```

If loaded into the REPL and executing the function, we get the correct result.

> *Main> depth algae
> 2

For just 400 elements, at this point you would be done as it is still a "small" problem and the run time should be below noticeable.
In order to speed it up, one idea could be to add data automatically to Composed elements (such as the depth) so you can prune  the tree.
The same idea at search time could be a form of memoization.